# Kentico Unit Testing on method with DocumentHelper

Tags: unit-testing, static, kentico

I have a method which is using DocumentHelper API from Kentico:

```
public static TreeNode GetDocument(string pageType, string aliasPath)
{
     var document = DocumentHelper.GetDocuments().Types(pageType).Path(aliasPath, PathTypeEnum.Single).FirstOrDefault();
     return document;
}
```

I wanted to do a unit test for this method, but I'm not sure how can I fake the DocumentHelper output. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You have several options:

- Create a non-static wrapper around `DocumentHelper`. It shouldn't contain any logic apart from passing parameters. Make the wrapper implement an interface and then create mocks implementing that interface.
- If you have the Enterprise edition of Visual Studio, you can take advantage of ["Microsoft Fakes (Unit Test Isolation)"](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/compare/) and let it generate fake assemblies for you.
  [image: Add fakes assembly]

  - And then use shims:
    [image: Use shims]
    See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/using-shims-to-isolate-your-application-from-other-assemblies-for-unit-testing)
- Create a wrapper using [delegates](http://adventuresdotnet.blogspot.nl/2011/03/mocking-static-methods-for-unit-testing.html). (No real advantage compared to the first approach.)